unable to interact on iOS (react-native, web based)
I'm developing React & Next.js based web / app service.
it's being published on both iOS and android using react-native (with ExpoGo)
All of a sudden, even plain input and button started not working on ios physical device.
(also works on web of course with environment set to mobile)
it works on android, ios simulator, desktop except ios physical device.
when i see VERCEL logs, it turned out that on ios real device it's only getting images not pages or apis
so it looks like there's a problem fetching JS Bundle.
can i get any help about what just happend or how to solve this problem??
below is React native code covering web
import { memo, useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import {
  BackHandler,
  ColorSchemeName,
  Platform,
  StyleProp,
  StyleSheet,
  ViewStyle,
  useColorScheme,
  useWindowDimensions,
} from 'react-native';
import { WebView, WebViewMessageEvent } from 'react-native-webview';
import { WebViewNavigation, WebViewSourceUri } from 'react-native-webview/lib/WebViewTypes';
import { StatusBar, StatusBarStyle } from 'expo-status-bar';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import Lottie from 'lottie-react-native';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@emotion/react';
import styled from '@emotion/native';

import theme from './src/theme';

interface IContainer {
  isModal: boolean;
  isDarkMode: boolean;
}

const Container = styled.View<IContainer>(({ theme, isModal, isDarkMode }) => ({
  flex: 1,
  backgroundColor: isModal
    ? `${theme.colors.black}80`
    : isDarkMode
    ? theme.colors.black
    : theme.colors.white,
}));

const SplashContainer = styled.View(({ theme }) => ({
  ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  backgroundColor: theme.colors.primary.default,
}));

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

const getScript = (colorScheme: ColorSchemeName) => `
  document.querySelector('html').classList.remove('light', 'dark');

  document.querySelector('html').classList.add('${colorScheme}');

  document.querySelector('html').style["color-scheme"] = '${colorScheme}';

  true;
`;

const App = () => {
  const { width } = useWindowDimensions();

  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  const [isLoad, setIsLoad] = useState(false);
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);
  const [isModal, setIsModal] = useState(false);
  const [isDarkMode, setIsDarkMode] = useState(colorScheme === 'dark');

  const webViewRef = useRef<WebView>(null);

  const lottieRef = useRef<Lottie>(null);

  const statusBarStyle = useMemo<StatusBarStyle>(() => {
    return isReady && (isModal || isDarkMode) ? 'light' : 'dark';
  }, [isReady, isModal, isDarkMode]);

  const webViewStyle = useMemo<StyleProp<ViewStyle>>(() => {
    return {
      marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
      backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? theme.colors.black : theme.colors.white,
    };
  }, []);

  const webViewContainerStyle = useMemo<StyleProp<ViewStyle>>(() => {
    return { flex: 1 };
  }, []);

  const source = useMemo<WebViewSourceUri>(() => {
    return { uri: 'https://myservice_name.vercel.app' };
  }, []);

  const injectedJavaScript = useMemo(() => getScript(colorScheme), []);

  const splashStyle = useMemo<StyleProp<ViewStyle>>(() => {
    return { width, height: (900 * width) / 1284, marginTop: -15 };
  }, [width]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
        webViewRef.current?.goBack();

        return true;
      });

      return () => backHandler.remove();
    }
  }, []);

  const onLoad = useCallback(() => {
    setIsLoad(true);
  }, []);

  const onMessage = useCallback(({ nativeEvent }: WebViewMessageEvent) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(nativeEvent.data);

    if (data.type === 'modal' && typeof data.isModal === 'boolean') {
      setIsModal(data.isModal);
    }
  }, []);

  const onNavigationStateChange = useCallback((event: WebViewNavigation) => {
    if (event.url.includes('https://myservice_name.vercel.app')) {
      webViewRef.current?.injectJavaScript(getScript(colorScheme));

      setIsDarkMode(colorScheme === 'dark');
    } else {
      webViewRef.current?.injectJavaScript(getScript('light'));

      setIsDarkMode(false);
    }
  }, []);

  const onLayout = useCallback(async () => {
    await SplashScreen.hideAsync();

    lottieRef.current?.play();
  }, []);

  const onAnimationFinish = useCallback(async () => {
    if (isLoad) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setIsReady(true);
      }, 1000);
    }
  }, [isLoad]);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <StatusBar style={statusBarStyle} />

      <Container isModal={isModal} isDarkMode={isDarkMode}>
        <WebView
          ref={webViewRef}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          autoManageStatusBarEnabled={false}
          overScrollMode="never"
          allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures
          renderLoading={undefined}
          style={webViewStyle}
          containerStyle={webViewContainerStyle}
          source={source}
          injectedJavaScript={injectedJavaScript}
          onLoad={onLoad}
          onMessage={onMessage}
          onNavigationStateChange={onNavigationStateChange}
        />

        {!isReady && (
          <SplashContainer>
            <Lottie
              ref={lottieRef}
              loop={false}
              style={splashStyle}
              source={require('./assets/lotties/splash.json')}
              onLayout={onLayout}
              onAnimationFinish={onAnimationFinish}
            />
          </SplashContainer>
        )}
      </Container>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default memo(App);

